# How to access the function when using dynamic injecting component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component where I am dynamically injecting another component. Please refer the code shown below:

```
getID() {
    const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
        .resolveComponentFactory(CodesComponent).create(this.injector);
    componentRef.instance.terms = this.terms;
    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
    const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
        .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
    $(domElem).insertAfter($(event.target).closest('tr'));
}
```

Also there is a function in my component:

```
sayHello() {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

And my `CodesComponent` looks like below:

```
<p (click) = "sayHello()"></p>
```

Now question is how can I call `sayHello()` function from dynamically created component?

Comment: Is the sayHello function inside your parent component or dynamically created component?

Comment: You can't use normal DOM manipulation to create Angular components since it doesn't perform the necessary compilation steps. See: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @ManzurKhan sayHello function is in my parent component.

Comment: Hi @TavishAggarwal, would you please show your code for the dynamic component, `CodesComponent`?

Comment: @Narm `<p (click) = "sayHello()"></p>` this line of code I have in my dynamic component.

Comment: So your `sayHello()` function is a member of the parent/container component where you then call `getID()` and create the dynamic component which only contains the template `<p (click) = "sayHello()"></p>`?

Comment: you got it Right @Narm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your use case I would recommend using Angulars dependency injection to **inject the parent component into your dynamic component**.

Here is a working [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-j8nsvr) for you.

**Code in your parent component**

```
import {
  Component, ViewChild, AfterContentInit, ComponentFactoryResolver,
  Compiler, ViewContainerRef, NgModule, NgModuleRef
} from '@angular/core';


import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;
  private cmpRef;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.getID();
  }

  public sayHello(): void{
    alert("Hello!");
  }

  private getID(): void {
    @Component({
      template: `<h2>This is a dynamic component</h2>
      <p (click)="_parent.sayHello()">Click me!</p>`
    })
    class DynamicComponent {
      constructor(public _parent: AppComponent) { }
    }
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule
      ],
      declarations: [DynamicComponent],
    }) class DynamicModule { }

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(DynamicModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
      comp.componentType === DynamicComponent
    );

    this.cmpRef = this._container.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```